# custom input & output fields for azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am not sure if this is an option. I require it badly, and cannot find any references of it.

When integrating between an HTTP Triggered Azure Function within your Logic App flow, you are requested to pass a body object for the function to digest:

[image: Azure Function in Logic App]

I am hoping for a way to customize the Request Body inputs, to make it have a strict template structure, in and out.

In:

[image: Azure Fn Template Fields]

Out:

[image: Custom Output]

(The function returns an Object)

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Logic Apps Custom Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/logic-apps/custom-connector-overview).

You can create one of these from a Postman collection or using an OpenAPI definition. You can get hold of the OpenAPI definition from the Function App.

With a custom connector, you have a bit more control over the request and response. This will allow the users of your connector to provide inputs when used in a Logic App and also receive tokens from the response. These can then be used in further Logic App steps.

Answer (score 0):

Just hard coded it to the fields I require it using the Logic App syntax and it responds to satisfaction

```
@{body('function-name')?['property']}
```

Haven't tried the Custom Connector